# Node.js how to structure an HTTP REST APi project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I am going to learn Node.js and right now I was trying to make a small demo project which implements an HTTP REST service.
My idea is to divide the APIs (url) by Resources and end up in a structure like the following one:

```
- user
 > index.js
 > post.js
 > put.js
 > delete.js
 > functions.js
- person
 > index.js
- index.js
```

So, if you are familiar with ASP.NET Web Api, I am trying to make every module of Node.js a Controller and every web method a single file (.js), in order to have an high maintainability in the future.

**Question**
Right now, my index.js file return the following:

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer();
```

How can I configure a specific "Request Handler" in each file by using this module? At the moment the `createServer()` method return a `server` object can use a single `server.on('request', function)` while I need to handle each request in a different file.

Comment: What you could do is use [express.js](http://expressjs.com/), create the server in your main file, and have `post`, `put`... returns `Router` object that you can attach to the server.

Comment: You need to check the request method and parse the url to build a handler module name. Another possible solution to manually configure the application, but that would be non-DRY.

Comment: Thank you guys, then I will start to have a look at http://expressjs.com/, and move forward from there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bigger projects Node.js and RESTful API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36300362/bigger-projects-node-js-and-restful-api)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go ahead learning with the help of some framework. They provide scaffolding of project.

If you are developing a complete web app(MVC) then go for [ExpressJs](https://expressjs.com/) or [SailsJs](http://sailsjs.org/)

If you are looking out to develop only API(No Views) then go for [Strongloop](https://strongloop.com/) or [Restify](http://restify.com/)

There are many more frameworks but the above ones are popular.

Comment: Thanks, no I am implementing only Api for now but at this point I will consider express.

Comment: Just to keep the audience "updated" on my progresses, I spent now over a week on Express + Knex (Database) and + Bookshelf (ORM) and I have made a barely basic REST API project.
I would suggest to others to learn Express and Bookshelf, they can make life a lot easier and they "resemble" the .NET syntax/project structure